# What SQL can be used to extract a first and last name from a mixture of name fields

Tags: microsoft-access, sql, string-manipulation

Name field can be a mixture of formats, for example: Mr. First Last, Mr First Last, First M Last, First M. Last, First Last Snr, First M Last Snr, First Last-Last, etc.

Comment: Not strictly SQL, but you would need coding in a language such as VBA, which is included with Microsoft Office. Someone wiser would probably be able to answer

Answer (score 1):

You could use Regular Expressions (not sure what tools you have at your disposal?), or as the comment suggests a good scripting language, to strip the Mr./Mrs. etc. However as far as returning the First and Last name in order from a Name field that mixes them together as you displayed is more than likely next to impossible.

The reason for this is - how are you going to tell what is the first name and last name? Michael Matthew could actually be Matthew Michael. Or what if his full name was Michael Francis Matthew - mixed together in that format Michael Francis and Matthew could all be the first name. You may want to consider redesigning the structure of your db to separate First, Middle, and Last names.